# NameError: name 'name_index_count' is not defined

Tags: python, python-3.x, nameerror

I have inherited a python script which was written with 2.X in mind. I have gone through making it compatible with 3.9.12. The script digs through folders and parses various excel and text files. Due to its enormity, I do not know the details of every try/except block or loop within.

The essential structure is like this (note that there are lots of loops I purposefully left out because they are irrelevant to the variables I had issues with);

```
if data_update == 1:
    for filename in glob.glob(filemove):
        newfilename2 = str(newfilename3[0])
        newcsvfilepath = newfilename2+"_"+CSVT+".csv"
    data_update_file = newcsvfilepath
    data_update_fileread = newcsvfilepath
try:
                try:
                        for line in read_it.splitlines():
                            name_index_count = 0
                            for y in name_dex:
                                name_index_count = name_index_count + 1
                except:
                    failp = str(name_index_count)
    if start_New == 1:
        filenameGo = data_update_fileread
```

The errors I get are;

1.

```
line 2391, in <module>                                                         
    failp = [str(ExTetF), deltamsg444, newfilecountLOG, newfilefailcountLOG,  "TryFail", str(Print_List[2]), str(Print_List[10]), str(name_index_count),  str(index), str(Store_Index),  Parser,  filename_norm,  yy,  linstr]
NameError: name 'name_index_count' is not defined
```

2. line 2553, in 
   filenameGo = data_update_fileread
   NameError: name 'data_update_fileread' is not defined

To me, it all looks fine. I wouldn't know where to start. These are the only locations the two variables in error are defined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `except` block you reference `name_index_count` but it's defined in the `try` block before it.  If the `try` block fails before `name_index_count = 0` is run (perhaps an exception on `read_it.splitlines()`), then that variable won't  be declared in the `except` block. To fix, try setting `name_index_count` before the try/except section.

For the second error, if `glob.glob(fileremove)` returns an empty list, then `newcsvfilepath` won't be defined.  Try setting it to None or an empty string before the `for` block. Combining these should look like:

```py
if data_update == 1:
    newcsvfilepath = ""
    for filename in glob.glob(filemove):
        newfilename2 = str(newfilename3[0])
        newcsvfilepath = newfilename2+"_"+CSVT+".csv"
    data_update_file = newcsvfilepath
    data_update_fileread = newcsvfilepath
try:
    name_index_count = 0
    try:
        for line in read_it.splitlines():
        for y in name_dex:
            name_index_count = name_index_count + 1
    except:
        failp = str(name_index_count)
```

Comment: Thank you, that was just the ticket.